# No source control providers registered - How to register SCM in visual code on mac?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I see there are several questions about having no **active** source control providers in VS code. I get a slightly different error:

> No source control providers registered

I am on a mac with a recent both OSx update to Mojave (10.14) and a new version of vscode (Version 1.28.2).

I don't have xcode installed on my machine.

I want to use github.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you have git installed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue on Mac OS and I found that I had to go into *Code > Preferences > Settings*. Search for Git and then  Scroll down until the Entry for Git: Path is found. Click edit in Settings.
Follow the instructions.

I found the path to Git in a terminal

```
# which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Add to the end of the override file (in the right hand window of the VS Code settings editor, "" included.)

```
"git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git",
```

Now Git works.

Answer (score 11):

This video worked for me. Really weird. But somehow I seem to have disabled my builtin git extension. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFzQnl44_70

Answer (score 2):

Type
@builtin in #vscode extensions search bar.
We get a list of @builtin extensions. You can disable or enable them.
Enable #git and #github extensions if you want #git in #vscode, by default they are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all extensions, reload, reenable all extensions, reload. I had this issue and re-installed vscode, re cloned my project, and still was getting the error of no source control providers registered. But when I disabled all my extensions, then reloaded, then reenabled, the reloaded it fixed my source control.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I was having a similar problem with my vscode + mercurial extension.

My windows is setup as a portable install and mercurial is in one of my conda environments so hg.exe was not found automatically by the extension. I set hg.path = [path to hg.exe"] 
in my case this line as added to my user settings json file (File->Preferences->Settings, then search for git.path and click Edit in setttings.json):

> "hg.path": "C:\Users\myname\anaconda3\envs\py27merc\Scripts\hg.exe"

An equivalent path on the path might be something like "/usr/local/bin/hg"
depending how mercurial is installed on your system

git has a similar variable and if you have git installed in fashion so that it cannot be found automatically you might need to set it manually in a similar way like:

> "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"

assuming that /usr/local/bin/git is where your git executable is located

Answer (score 1):

One that helped me with this issue (in addition to adding `"git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"`):

- In your `settings.json` search for `"git.enabled": false` and set to `"git.enabled": true`

Answer (score 0):

You should install git in your computer and add `git.path` in VsCode - then it will work

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing .vscode file from root directory did the job.
I had the same extensions configured to my other MacBook so I pasted 
the extensions folder on .vscode file in the same directory and 
problem solved!